# Serving Static Files for Django Project with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up a deploy through Elastic Beanstalk for a simple Django app. The site seems to be working, but the static files are not being served correctly (styles and scripts are missing).

I have the following code inside `.ebextensions/django.config`

```
container_commands:
  01_collectstatic:
    Command: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: django_by_example_blog/wsgi.py
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: static/
```

When I deploy with the config above, the site returns "URL not found" for any route.

However, when I use the following configuration, the site works but styles are missing.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: django_by_example_blog/wsgi.py
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: static/
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you already tried quotes around `/static/`--i.e., `"/static/"`?

Comment: Yes. There also seems to be a problem with the `collectstatic` part of the configuration.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: @SonOfSeuss, Hard to say. I abandoned this approach in favor of S3 and NGINX server.